# Guest Additions 5.2.18 not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution, guest-additions

My current version of VertualBox was quite old but working well with WinXP as the guest OS. So, I decided to upgrade VB to the latest version before installing a new copy of Win10. I updated my list of repositories and then updated VB with apt-get. I ended up with VB 5.1, not the latest. I purged the apt-get installs of VB, downloaded the latest versions of VirtualBox, it's extensions, and Guest Additions all with the same version numbers, 5.2.18, and installed them. Then I installed Win10 successfully. Everything seems to be working fine except I have no cut-n-paste sharing nor any screen control. When the guest starts up, the CD-ROM is mounted with the correct ISO but it doesn't seem to be integrating the guest's screen with the host.

I've spent the day Googling this issue and even though there is a lot of similar issues like this posted on the Internet, I have tried it all but nothing fixes my problem. It wouldn't be so bad but Win10 installed with a default screen driver that only supports 1024 by 768 mode. that's half of the host's resolution.

I really need help with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind!

I started this morning with a fresh mind and eyes. I went back to the Oracle page on Guest Additions and toward the bottom of the page there was a pretty detailed explanation on how it's installed. I didn't need to download a correct version of GuestAdditions since the most correct version is included by the VB install itself. As for the monitor resolution goes, I found a very good thread that says to remove the resolution hint from the setup and just put none in the setting. This is what was limiting the guest OS's resolution.